# How to search hyper link tag based on key pressed

Tags: html, jsp, hyperlink

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="viewprofile.jsp">1. View Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="chngpass.jsp">2. Change Password</a></li>
      <li><a href="singout.jsp">3. Sign Out</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

As shown in above code, I want top open particular hyper link based on number pressed
ex- if I press '1' then hyper link should go to 'viewprofile.jsp'
    if I press '2' then hyper link should go to 'chngpass.jsp'

In this way I want to perform, how to do it.

Comment: Show us your efforts on javascript.

Comment: I am implementing in jsp page, its standard html tag how can i put inside a javascript

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework? Basically it can be done with javascript.

Comment: i am not using any kind of framework. I Am just Using Standared HTML tag. Is it possible to do way i described in html tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample example with JQuery:

```js
$(function() {

  var lnks = $('a').map(function() {
    return this.href; //<-- fetch all hrefs in array
  }).get();

  $(document).on('keypress', function(e) { //<-- detect key press
    var i = e.which - 49; //<-- ascii value of 1 is 49
    if (lnks[i]) //<-- got link
      window.location.href = lnks[i]; //<-- load page
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/">1. geeksforgeeks</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.w3schools.com">2. w3schools</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://javatutorials.com/">3. javatutorials</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```